# How to list oracle data and present in HTML with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodes, node-oracledb

I have a giant headache, the case is as follows.

I need to present data from a table that is in oracle in an HTML page, I can do it directly by presenting the console.log on the page, but that's not what I really need. I wanted to understand how to manipulate table data in oracle and list in HTML.

```js
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

// Rotas

app.get('/teste', function (req, res) {
  SelectBasico(req, res);
});

app.get('/alo', function (req, res) {});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/src/index.html');
});

// Funções

async function run() {
  // Função de Conexão com BD
  let connection;

  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({
      user: '///',
      password: '///',
      connectionString: '///',
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

run();
```

Comment: You might find this older series of articles about creating a REST service with node-oracledb useful for learning: https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-db-examples/tree/main/javascript/rest-api

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
const express = require('express');
const oracledb = require('oracledb');

const app = express();

// Connection details for the Oracle database
const connectionString = 'hostname:port/database';
const user = 'username';
const password = 'password';

// Connect to the database
oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    connectionString: connectionString,
    user: user,
    password: password
  },
  function(err, connection) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection was successful!');

    // Execute a SQL query
    const query = 'SELECT * FROM table';
    connection.execute(query, [], (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        return;
      }
      console.log('Query was successful!');

      // Render the HTML template and pass the query results as a local variable
      app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.render('template.html', { data: result.rows });
      });
    });
  }
);

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Server is listening on port 3000');
});
```

Comment: Does my template.html page need to be empty? Or rather, should I make a call on her?

Comment: You need to write all the html to display this data in tabular form

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer.

Comment: This is one of my biggest doubts, how is the syntax to call this data? for example, I have a field in the table, called "codemp", how would I call it in the html?

Comment: This executes the SQL query *once* for the entire life of the web server instance, and then creates an API endpoint that just always returns the same data.  I imagine a more common use case would be to query the database *each time* the API endpoint is accessed?